# yarn install lint and test fails randomly on jenkins ci build

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2, yarnpkg-v2

Team,
I am learning yarn and it is very wierd i get no logs to see what the issue is.
my build randomly fail and when i retry they work well. also every time i retry it is fresh jenkins pod agent that runs the pipeline so there is no cache issue i believe.

logs show only `FAILED` but no info.

```
11:54:23  ++ export YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS=false
11:54:23  ++ YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS=false
11:54:23  ++ export YARN_CHECKSUM_BEHAVIOR=update yarn
11:54:23  ++ YARN_CHECKSUM_BEHAVIOR=update
11:54:23  ++ yarn install --verbose
11:54:24  + echo 1
11:54:24  [Pipeline] archiveArtifacts
11:54:24  Archiving artifacts
11:54:24  Recording fingerprints
11:54:24  [Pipeline] echo
11:54:24  #!/usr/bin/env bash
11:54:24  
11:54:24  export YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS=false
11:54:24  export YARN_CHECKSUM_BEHAVIOR=update yarn
11:54:24  
11:54:24  yarn install --verbose FAILED
11:54:24  [Pipeline] sh
11:54:25  + cat logs/yarn_install.txt
11:54:25  [Pipeline] unstable
11:54:25  WARNING: #!/usr/bin/env bash
11:54:25  
11:54:25  export YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS=false
11:54:25  export YARN_CHECKSUM_BEHAVIOR=update yarn
11:54:25  
11:54:25  yarn install --verbose FAILED
```

pipeline is below

```
          sh script: "ci/pipelines/ci-buildauth.sh", label: "Run buildauth"
          script {
            def installSuccess = logCallReturnStatus(
              [
                "#!/usr/bin/env bash",
                "",
                "export YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS=false",
                "export YARN_CHECKSUM_BEHAVIOR=update yarn",
                "",
                "yarn install --verbose",
              ].join("\n"),
              "logs/yarn_install.txt",
              true,
            )
```

any hint how can i debug why my pipeline works on retry and fails randomly sometimes?

I want to see the root cause and fix. thanks.

same happens with yarn lint and then with yarn test.